# Formdata is not appending vlaues

Tags: angular, file-upload

I need to submit a form including upload file. Am trying to dynamically compose the formdata but it is not working.

```
  const formData = new FormData();

  Object.keys(this.Form.controls).forEach(key => {
    formData.append(key,this.Form.get(key).value);
    console.log(key,this.Form.get(key).value)// values are available
  });

  console.log(formData) // in console i get FormData {}

  this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
   _id: [''], 
   name: ['', Validators.required],
   photo: ['',Validators.required],   
   field1: ['',Validators.required],
   field2: ['',Validators.required],
   field3: ['',Validators.required],
   field4: ['',Validators.required],   
 });
```

Comment: Sorry guys i got the answer, we cannot directly console formData need to iterate it!

Comment: Check in-network call, It will be shown there

Comment: Ok Sure, Thanks!